# ViewModel values not reflecting in the View through MVVM WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, prism

I have a View where I am binding the values to this through the View-Model by MVVM pattern & I am having a functionality which will be turning the View into images/PDF files. If I am having more records for creating the PDF files, then i add the values to a observable collection and loop though it.

Logic:

```
for (int i = collection.Count(); i > 0; i--)
{
    // Generate the values(Properties) for the View with collection[i-1]
    // Convert the View into images and generate the PDF files
}
```

This is working fine when I am having collection count as 1, but when I am having more records to convert, then the first record data is being converted to Image/PDF from the View and from the second record also the same image/pdf is being displayed where I am facing the issue.

The issue was, before the values are reflecting on the View from the second record the code was trying to Generate the images from the initial first record data.

Try1: Added Loaded event for the View, its hitting for the first time when the View is brought into scope and from second time its not hitting the event

Try2: Added a dummy hidden control at the end of the page to validate its value and the value in the ViewModel, verification shows that the values are same but still the values are not reflecting on the View.

Do I miss anything over here????

Comment: Reverse loops, why...

Comment: it can be forward or the reverse loop, anything can be considered there is no spl logic involved in this

Comment: Is it true that with reverse loop you get every time first item (i mean collection[0]) and with forward loop you get every time last item(collection[i-1])?